# Magento2 : Restrict new category creation on import products

Tags: magento-2.1, import

I want to restrict magento2 import from CSV that if product has a category path and category not exist then throw error to admin. Currently magento2 allow import products and it create new categories if not exist for given path.

I don't allow to create new categories on products CSV import.

> Is there any setting for this in admin or How to customize it in
>   custom module?

Comment: I have the same question here. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: No, didn't get any solution yet.